# ASP.NET Identity Change Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity

I want to use ASP.NET Identity for several websites that i have created, and i do want to use the same database on each of them.

When i try to register two users with the same email, i get the "Name ****** is already taken." I have already set the field "RequireUniqueEmail = false" in IdentityConfig.

In the AspNetUsers i have a field called "web_id". It should be possible to create one identical user within one web_id, but it should be possible to create users with the same email on different web_id's.

Someone who knows how i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the source code of Identity UserValidator, [UserValidator](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/UserValidator.cs).  You can see if set "RequireUniqueEmail = false", it won't validate email anymore, that's not ideal.

There are two solutions I can think of:

1. Make (email, web_id) as a grouped key/index in db schema, in this case either of them duplicate is OK, but not both.  Then you handle the error when creating user, if failed to create user because of this index duplicate, then treat it as Duplicate Email.  Of course, you need to set "RequireUniqueEmail = false" in this case.
2. Or create a subclass of UserValidator or interface IUserValidator, implement your own logic to check (email, web_id), then set it to UserManager.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

If i set "RequireUniqueEmail = false", i still get this error message - "Name o******@hotmail.com is already taken. I am using the last version of Identity.

How do i make them as a grouped key/index in db schema?
Creating a subclass of UserValidator seems like the best option, but i dont know how to implement that one with my own logic.. Do you have an example of doing this?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have example, maybe you can google 'UserValidator identity custom' and figure out by yourself. Herer is one, https://gist.github.com/blachniet/7394005

Comment: That actually helped a lot. Thanks. I have passed the UserValidator, BUT now i met a new problem. "Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details." And it shows this as the "error-line" var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

Comment: Seems like it checks one more time, after the CustomUserValidator, because i tried a try/catch, and i got this: ErrorMessage "User name o******@hotmail.com is already taken.".